# In react, display a component on the right of sidebar after clicking button without changing layout

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

I would like to display such a component in the picture after clicking the "+" button. such a component should be at the right of the sidebar and over the main section.

The previous layout is a 2-col-grid and will not be changed, just a new component created over the others.

What I am confused is how to set the layout (e.g. using tailwind) and what is the proper way to place code of the new component (is it better to make it a child component of the sidebar, or make sidebar, main, and the new component the same level?)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try to add the component with position: absolute. And change top, left, right, or bottom to show on the button click

Comment: Are you using mui ? you could use popover if that's the case

Comment: I used absolute with negative value in tailwind so the component can be displayed outside of its relative parent (i.e. the sidebar)   It is enough to my current development but I still expect a standard method since such a design quite common

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I understand where you put it is up to you. Try to be as semantic as you can with your HTML.

About the method to use, I usually go for a ternary inside `className`, for example:

```
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
<Sidebar>
   <div className={`${isClicked ? 'opacity-1 pointer-events-auto' : 'opacity-0 pointer-events-none'}`}></div>
</Sidebar>
```

Eventually I could make use of `z-index` if needed. I used tailwind classes as you suggest, but you can add some custom and style it with CSS.